# weird 'id's and checkboxes behaviour with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a simple 'To do list' using React Hooks. Right now I am having two problems:

1) first two list items have identical 'id' values (even though I increment the counter...)
[image]

2) the checkboxes are checked and updated only after double click

I will be grateful for your tips, clues, review, advice and solutions! :-)

This is the 'ToDoList' component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ListItem from './ToDoItem';

const ToDoList = () => {
let [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
let initialItem = {
    id: counter,
    name: '',
    time: '',
    finished: false,
}

const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => console.log('THE ARRAY OF TASKS', tasks), [tasks]);

const [task, setTask] = useState(initialItem);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    setTask(prevState => {
        return { ...prevState, id: counter}
    });
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
    setTask(initialItem);
}

const deleteItem = (id) => {
    let newTasks = tasks.filter((item, index) => {
        return index !== id
    });
    setTasks(newTasks);
}

const handleCheckbox = (val, id) => {
    tasks.map((element) => {
        if (element.id === id) {
            element.finished = val
        }
    })
    console.log('UPDATED TASKS', tasks)
}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input placeholder="Add a task" value={task.name} onChange={(e) => {
                let value = e.target.value;
                setTask(prevState => {
                    return { ...prevState, name: value }
                })
            }}></input>

            <input placeholder="Add time" value={task.time} onChange={(e) => {
                let value = e.target.value;
                setTask(prevState => {
                    return { ...prevState, time: value }
                })
            }}></input>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ListItem tasks={tasks} delete={deleteItem} checked={handleCheckbox} />
    </div>
)
}

export default ToDoList;
```

And this is the 'ListItem' component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


function ListItem(props) {
    const tasks = props.tasks;
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    return tasks.map((element, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>
            {element.name}: {element.time}
            <button onClick={() => props.delete(index)}>delete</button>
            <label className="container">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={element.finished}
                    onChange={(e) => setIsChecked(!isChecked)} 
                    onClick={(e) => {props.checked(isChecked, element.id);}}>
                </input>
                <span className="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    })
}

export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

State setters are asynchronous, meaning the line after the setCounter may run before the counter's value has actually been updated.

In your case, it looks like the only time you update the counter is before adding a new task, so you can refactor the code so the task adding happens in an effect when the counter changes:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCounter(count => count + 1);
};
useEffect(() => {
    setTask(prevState => {
        return { ...prevState, id: counter}
    });
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
    setTask(initialItem);
}, [counter]);
```

Although now, you may have the same problem with using task when setTask hasn't finished. However, you probably don't need to set the task, use the task, and then reset the task all in the state like that. Try this instead:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCounter(count => count + 1);
};
useEffect(() => {
    const newTask = {...task, id: counter};
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
    setTask(initialItem);
}, [counter]);
```

This way, no code has to wait on the task state to update and you get no race conditions. (This assumes "task" isn't likely to change immediately before submitting, so it's safe to just pull the current value of "task" when creating the new object.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Your answer fixed the issue of the ids but still the weird thing happens =  when I fire the application an empty task is rendered and added to the array of tasks with the id of 1. So in the console it looks like this: 'ARRAY OF TASKS': [], 'ARRAY OF TASKS: [{id: 1, name:"", time:"", finished: false}]; It's as if useEffect doesn't wait for the counter and fires instantly after window onload.

Comment: Yeah, that's because useEffect will actually run once when the component mounts. To avoid this, you can start the count at 0, since you're incrementing it on submission anyway, and then prematurely return from the effect callback if count is 0. That way it won't do anything when `count === 0`, the mount, but once count changes to anything else -- like 1 -- it will run.

Comment: Ohh thank you @IceMetalPunk,     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (counter > 0) {
        const newTask = { ...task, id: counter };
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
        setTask(initialItem);
        }
    }, [counter]); THAT FIXED THE IDS :D thank you so much! Do you have any idea about the checkboxes?